# Зависает UI при пивязке к ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет.

Пытаюсь привязать двумерный массив цветов.

Делаю это так:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Rect">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" Width="10" Height="10"/>
    </DataTemplate>

                                         ...

     <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Rect}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

И ViewNodel:

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Color>> colors = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Color>>();

public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Color>> Colors
{
    get { return colors; }
}

colors.Clear();
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    ObservableCollection<Color> level = new ObservableCollection<Color>();

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        level.Add(pixels[y * width + x]);
    }
    colors.Add(level);
 }
```

Т.е. в итоге получается такая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выполнении цикла зависает UI, причем надолго и наглухо. Везде и всюду говорят о `VirtualizingStackPanel`, но это не помогло.

С `DataGrid` виртуализация у меня работала, но сейчас задача усложняется привязкой двумерного массива.

Как решить проблему зависания? Или как привязать массив к `DataGrid`, но также без зависаний?

P.S.: хитрости с `OnRender` и `Visal` не подходят. Проходили. Не то.

Comment: Может проще создать изображение в коде и только потом отобразить его цельным куском?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, предполагается печать. Там еще в каждом квадрате будет текст. Качество печати будет низкое.

Comment: Слишком большая нагрузка на `ItemsControl`. будет тормозить при любых раскладах. Нужно на `Canvas` выводить. Да, и вы можете показывать пользователю одно, а печатать другое, это я о низком качестве.

Comment: @Bulson пробовал, при передаче зависает также. С `DataGrid` же как-то это работает?

Comment: Мы не знаем, что там "под капотом" у `DataGrid`, он ведь спецом заточен на вывод априори неизвестно заранее большого количества данных, т.е. может у него есть какой-нибудь спецбуфер большого объема.

Comment: @Bulson понадобился интерактив (выделение, замена и тп). Пробовал картинкой рисовать, при увеличении опять же качество текста очень низкое. А отрисовывать каждый раз - затратно, начинает виснуть.

Comment: @Bulson моя идея в том, чтобы заметь шаблон ячейки на цветной квадрат с буквой внутри. И зацепить позицию в матрице на конткретную ячейку. Но не получается одновременно шаблон сделать и зацепить на матрицу.

Comment: Похоже, что вам нужно воспользоваться возможностями [Windows.UI.Composition](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Windows/Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10-Version-1511/Creating-fluid-and-beautiful-UI-using-the-new-Visual-Layer)

Comment: Можно увидеть пример как вы проверяли работоспособность варианта с `DataGrid`?

Comment: @Foggy Finder я имел в виду, что для обычной колекции данных работает виртуализация в DataGrid. Она не ждет когда вся коллекция загрузится.

Comment: @Bulson Автор пишет на WPF, там нет Windows.UI.Composition.